# Widgetsize for different Android versions

Tags: android, resize, manifest, android-appwidget

i developed an appwidget that can be used for different sizes.
Since it is possible to resize an app on Android 4.2 i don't want to overfill the widgetlist on those devices. But for customers with an older Android version i want to provide the widget in some different sizes.
Is there a condition-xml-tag or some similar possibility to check the Android version in the Manifest and then to add some more sizes in case of an old version?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The `receiver` tag in your Manifest that you create for each widget has an `android:enabled` attribute and it can get that boolean value from a resource file.

Therefore you can write your widget's receiver as (the important line is the `android:enabled` one):

```
<receiver
    android:name=".YourAppWidgetProvider"
    android:enabled="@bool/your_appwidget_enabled"
    android:label="@string/your_appwidget_label" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/your_appwidget_info" />
</receiver>
```

And then create a `bools.xml` in your `res/values` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="your_appwidget_enabled">false</bool>
</resources>
```

And another `bools.xml` in your `res/values-v11` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="your_appwidget_enabled">true</bool>
</resources>
```

This will mean that YourAppWidgetProvider (and the widget described in `your_appwidget_info`) will only appear on v11+ devices. You can use the same approach to disable/enable any number of widgets based on whatever Android version you want.

Comment: Exactly what i was searching for. Thanks